# running multiquery inside for loop mysql

Tags: ajax, serialization

i am trying to runa a multiquery inside a for loop. The post variables come from a dynamic table

```
    if ($resultset->num_rows == 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["savi_account_number"]); $i++) {
            $insert = "INSERT INTO `savings_transactions_table` (`id`, `receipt_id`, `sub_code`, `savings_account`, `user_id`, `amount`, `dr`, `cr`, `actual_balance`, `available_balance`, `created_user`, `created_date`)
VALUES (NULL, '$receipt_id', '" . $_POST['savings_product'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['savi_account_number'][$i] . "', '$member_id', '" . $_POST['savi_dep_amount'][$i] . "', '0', '" . $_POST['savi_dep_amount'][$i] . "', '0', '0', '$user_id', '$create_date');";
            $insert.="INSERT INTO `gl_transactions_table` (`id`, `member_id`, `posting_product`, `product_account`, `gl_account`, `dr`, `cr`, `trx_code`, `trx_type`, `trx_reference`, `posted_date`, `posted_by`)
VALUES (NULL, '$member_id', '" . $_POST['savings_product'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['savi_account_number'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['savings_cap_gl'][$i] . "', '0', '" . $_POST['savi_dep_amount'][$i] . "', '$deposit_type', '$transaction_type', '$transaction_reference', '$create_date', '$user_id')";
            $res = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $insert);}
```

but the query does not insert all values, but only one line in db.

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
if ($resultset->num_rows == 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["savi_account_number"]); $i++) 
    {
        $insert .= "INSERT INTO `savings_transactions_table` (`id`, `receipt_id`, `sub_code`, `savings_account`, `user_id`, `amount`, `dr`, `cr`, `actual_balance`, `available_balance`, `created_user`, `created_date`)
VALUES (NULL, '$receipt_id', '" . $_POST['savings_product'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['savi_account_number'][$i] . "', '$member_id', '" . $_POST['savi_dep_amount'][$i] . "', '0', '" . $_POST['savi_dep_amount'][$i] . "', '0', '0', '$user_id', '$create_date');";

    }
    $res = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $insert);
```

run query outside the `for loop`

Comment: sorry, doesn't work. I have two queries that needs to be iterated as shown in the code. still it posts one entry. thanks

Comment: only a single entry was inserted, not the multiple lines. i am getting the information from form serialized, the data is on a dynamic table in front end.thx

Comment: `echo count($_POST["savi_account_number"]` and see length of your data

Comment: Error No: 2014 - MySQL error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now 
Query:---thats the error

Comment: you first echo the `echo count($_POST["savi_account_number"]` and see the length of your data

Comment: yes it gives 2 when i have two entries in my dynamic table. same error given still. I tried posting from same page (currently i have ajax call to another php file) its the same result. thanks for any help

Comment: HI bhargav, i got this sorted out using PDO method for the sql multi query. thanks for the help...